# How do I dump a Postgres database QUICKLY

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-backups, pg-dump

I have a massive Postgres 9.1 database (~450 GB) that I need to copy to a new machine, where I want to upgrade to Postgres 12.

Using `pg_dump` stalls out after a few hours, writing only 60 GB. How can I speed up the process dramatically?

Comment: What kind of dump are you generating? SQL dump or custom dump? Did you check `pg_stat_activity` to see if pg_dump is maybe waiting for something? Did you consider using `pg_upgrade` instead of pg_dump/pg_restore?

Comment: You mention it stalls out at 60GB. Is the target disk full at that point? Also, are you dumping over SSH? If so, the bottleneck will likely be the network speed.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is going to do what `pg_dump` does faster than `pg_dump` itself. Shut down access to the database while dumping if at all possible. Check the system for other sources of load (particularly I/O load) and remove them if possible. Check if the drive is failing. Don't write the dump to the same disk that the database is being read from (if another disk isn't available on the source machine, consider something like `pg_dump whatever | ssh anothermachine 'cat > db.sql'`). Or, just have patience.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dumping the database over ssh, add the `-Z` flag, followed by the zip level, to compress the output of `pg_dump`. e.g., `pg_dump -Z 9`

See the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html